# How are block nested loop joins optimised for disk reads?

Tags: join, optimization

Quick question on reasonable optimisations on BNLJ:

Say we have following relations:

- A(a,b,d)
- B(c,m,n,ww,d)

And following query:

```
Select A.a, A.b, B.c  
From A join B using (d)  
Where A.b > 800 AND B.m = 'zack'
```

In this case all possible optimisation on relations are the following:

```
A.a, A.b A.d (A.b > 800 A) 
B.c B.d (B.m = 'zack' B)
```

Where we first have selection, then projection.

And now we have two ways to go about this: A as outer loop and B as inner, A as inner loop and B as outer.

Ok, I know all the stuff about buffer pages and the formulas.
However, I am getting confused on this thing.

Do we first do the optimisations for BOTH relations (regardless of what loop they are) and storing the 'optimised' pages in memory and then fetching them to perform the join (and in both cases A-B or B-A we use the optimised pages for BOTH)?

Or do we do optimisations only for relation we choose as an outer loop and don't do ANY optimisations on the relation we choose as an inner loop?

Or we do optimisations on both as we go along?

And say if our optimised version for outer loop is bigger than the buffer space, can we still stored the 'filtered' records in memory and rely that BNLJ will pick them when doing consecutive runs of the outer loop?

So in general what is the whole process of making sure that BNLJ would be executed as efficiently as possible provided the query above?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking in general or specifically about MySQL?  If specifically about MySQL, then you run the risk of "overlearning".  Such details could easily change between releases or in very particular circumstances.

Comment: I am asking in general, whether such assumptions are reasonable. Thanks!